# Copy of subsite is still serving index.php in the links?

Tags: index

I have 2 subsites on the same apache server both pointing to the same craft database.  The original subsite has the normal links, but, the subsite copy has index.php in all of the links.  Can someone point me in the right direction to remove the index.php references? NOTE: .htaccess is correct and the same on both sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the setting `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true` on either both sites, or in the wildcard config.

```
<?php

return [
    '*' => [
        // ...
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        // ...
    ]
];
```

You can read more about it here:
https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php

Comment: The default value of auto was the problem.  For some reason it evaluated the sub-sites to have different capabilities.  Thanks.